# Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, api-versioning

I am trying to design a API versioning, but I am getting following error

> Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and
>   had all constraints satisfied

I didn't want to duplicate all controller methods instead I just override whatever changed but unchanged causes the error. is that bad practice what I am trying? any solution to my problem?

```
[ApiVersion( "1.0" )]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class HeartbeatController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    public virtual IActionResult Beat()
    {
        return Ok(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("0.9")]
    public virtual IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(Environment.MachineName);
    }
}


[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class HeartbeatController : V1.Controllers.HeartbeatController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public override IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("this is version 2 " + Environment.MachineName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance can be tricky and it's not always obvious which attributes are inherited and which aren't. In this case, **RouteAttribute** and **HttpGetAttribute** are inherited, but **ApiVersionAttribute** is not.

The following configuration will get you what you're looking for:

```
using static System.Environment;

[ApiVersion( "1.0" )]
[Route( "api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]" )]
public class HeartbeatController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual IActionResult Get() => Ok( MachineName );
}

[ApiVersion( "2.0" )]
public class HeartbeatController : V1.HeartbeatController
{
    public override IActionResult Get() => Ok( "this is version 2 " + MachineName );
}
```